# Union for Columns of Different Datatypes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the site (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) and I am trying to understand `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. A small portion of the "Customers" and "Suppliers" Table is given in the Image below.

I'm confused why when I run the `UNION` for the Columns `City` from `Customers` and `PostalCode` from `Suppliers` which are Columns of different datatypes I don't receive an Error. (Seen in Image 2)

[image]
[image]

Thank You

Comment: Union joins two result sets together into one final result set, but they share the same starting columns. So if you union those two queries as you suggested you'll end up with Cities and Postal codes in the same column. Union ALL just does the same thing but doesn't drop anything, regular Union pulls distinct records.

Comment: It might be using the datatype of the first table, or it might be using the least-restrictive datatype.   Try reversing the order of the two sides of the union and see what happens.

Comment: Outside of being different character limits of Varchars I don't see how they would be different datatypes. They both appear to be varchars, since no numeric / integer datatype will return whole numbers with a leading zero.

Comment: @ZACK Thanks. Yes, I initially thought `PostalCode` was just an `int`. However, when I try `CustomerID` instead of `City` in the code that I run, I still don't receive an Error despite the fact that `PostalCode` is `varchar` and `CustomerID`is definitely not of this type.

Comment: In that case it could be as Tab said, where it converts the datatype automatically to the query that initially creates the column. All queries that are unioned to the first query will conform to the limitations of the first query. So if you switch it around and make the varchar union to the integer column you might be able to trigger an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions of the columns that are part of a **UNION** operation do not have to be the same, but they must be compatible through implicit conversion. When data types differ, the resulting data type is determined based on the rules for [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190309.aspx). When the types are the same but differ in [precision, scale, or length,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190476.aspx) the result is determined based on the same rules for combining expressions